# X86: addressing mode - register value change

Tags: assembly, x86-64, addressing-mode

This maybe very silly, but have a small doubt regarding these type of instructions:

```
MOV EBX,dword ptr [RAX + 0x28]
```

Does this change the value of `RAX`? Something like:

Mov the value pointed by `RAX + 0x28` in `EBX` and then add, `Add RAX, 0x28`. So, in short, does the value of `RAX` change after this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it uses the value of `RAX`, it does not change it.

It's like having a C expression `i + 1`. This doesn't change the value of `i`, it only uses it. What you describe would be like the expression `i += 1`.

Answer (score 3):

No, unlike ARM or PowerPC, x86 doesn't have any addressing modes that write back the effective address to the base register.

Also no explicit pre/post inc/dec addressing modes like m68k.  (push/pop and `movs`/`stos`/`lods`/etc. have *implicit* increment/decrement addressing built-in, for RSP or for RDI/RSI.)